# How to nicely denote the alternative of three conditions?

Tags: haskell

Assume I have a character `c :: Char` . Now I want to see if it's equal to `a` or `isDigit`:

```
isAOrDigit = (||) <$> (=='a') <*> (isDigit)
```

So far so good. But now I want to see if it's equal to `a`, `isDigit` or is between `d` and `g`. Unfortunately, since `||` only accepts 2 arguments, I can't say `` (||) <$> (=='a') <*> (isDigit) <*> (`elem`['d'..'g']) ``.

Is there any nice way to write this or do i have to fall back to this:

```
isACOrDigitOrDG c = c == 'a' || isDigit c || c `elem` ['d'..'g']
```

?

Comment: @4castle Nice! Sadly, won't work if the condition is more arbitrary...

Comment: @4castle 'Twas my bad, I provided a too simple example... Maybe my edited version of my Q will help

Comment: ```foldMap (Any.) [('a'==), isDigit, (`elem` ['d'..'g'])]``` isn't too bad, although it doesn't have exactly the same type.

Comment: @DanielWagner Aren't you just missing a call to `getAny` to fix that, though? `getAny . foldMap ...`

Answer (score 7):

You can use `sequence` to convert a `[a -> Bool]` to a `a -> [Bool]`. Then you can use `or` to combine that `[Bool]` value.

```
isACOrDigitOrDG = or . sequence
    [ (== 'a')
    , isDigit
    , (`elem` ['d'..'g'])
    ]
```

Answer (score 7):

You can lift the `(||)` operator:

```
(<||>) = liftA2 (||)

> :t (== 'a') <||> isDigit <||> (`elem` ['d'..'g'])
(== 'a') <||> isDigit <||> (`elem` ['d'..'g']) :: Char -> Bool

> (== 'a') <||> isDigit <||> (`elem` ['d'..'g']) $ 'a'
True
```

Comment: Note that you have to work a bit harder if you want this (or yours) to be short-circuiting: http://hackage.haskell.org/package/cond-0.4.1.1/docs/Control-Conditional.html#v:-60--124--124--62-

Comment: The advantage of lifting `(||)` over sequence- or monoid-based solutions, which are also nice, is that you can mix `||` and `&&` with this approach if you need to.

Comment: I thought I understood how to use liftA2 on boolean operators, but you have shown me there are some subtleties I didn't realize yet. Cool solution.

Comment: @ReinHenrichs No extra care is needed. The package you linked to takes extra care because it is trying to generalize over arbitrary monads; but the reader family of monads in particular is already sufficiently lazy in their "side effects". You can see it's so for yourself: `liftA2 (||) (const True) undefined undefined` returns `True` as necessary with no extra work.

Answer (score 3):

Depending on your definition of "nice", you could write

```
isACOrDigitOrDG :: Char -> Bool
isACOrDigitOrDG = anyOf [(== 'a'), isDigit, (`elem` ['d'..'g'])]
   where anyOf fs c = or (fs <*> [c])
      -- anyOf = (or .) . (. pure) . (<*>)
```

`or :: [Bool] -> Bool` is true if any value in its input is true. The applicative instance for lists says that `fs <*> xs` applies each function in `fs` to each value in `xs`, and collects the results in a single list (for our purposes here, the order doesn't matter). Since we only have one `Char`, we create a list so that `fs <*> [c]` applies each predicate to the input character. `or` then tells us if any of those applications succeeded.

Honestly, though? For a fixed set of predicates, there's nothing wrong with

```
isACOrDigitOrDG c = c == 'a' || isDigit c || c `elem` ['d'..'g']
```

Point-free style can be hit-or-miss; sometimes it captures the *idea* of what you want to do better than a pointed defintion, other times it's just terse for the sake of terseness. I often write a function in both styles before deciding which one I'll want to read later.

As a third option between the two, you might take advantage of a list comprehension:

```
isACOrDigitOrDG c = or [f c | f <- tests]
    where tests = [(== 'a')
                  ,isDigit
                  ,(`elem` ['d'..'g'])
                  ]
```

Comment: `Depending on your definition of "nice"` - Honestly, I don't have any such definition. I'm a newbie to Haskell, I'd sooner ask you what is the definition of "nice". But I note that, I suppose, Haskellers like point free and dislike function application when not necessary, so I *thought* that `c == 'a' || isDigit c || c `elem` ['d'..'g']` would *probably* not be considered nice by experienced Haskellers, hence my Q.

Comment: It was somewhat tongue-in-cheek, as it involves a bit of abstraction. I'll add some description of how `anyOf` gets built. (The point-free version is intentionally commented, as I'm not sure if anyone would ever find that "obvious".)

Comment: `anyOf fs c = any ($c) fs`. And then you can just inline it; `isACOrDigitOrDG c = any ($c) [...]`.

Comment: I distinctly remember use `($c)` when writing this up; I don't remember why I didn't include it. I think it got lost in the shuffle when I was trying to figure out if the OP wanted a point-free solution or not.

Answer (score 1):

Another version that is similar to the other answers and short circuiting:

```
isACOrDigitOrDG x = any ($x) [(=='a'), isDigit, (`elem` ['d'..'g'])]
```

or if you'd rather have the slightly ridiculous pointfree version:

```
isACOrDigitOrDG = flip any [(=='a'), isDigit, (`elem` ['d'..'g'])] . flip ($)
```

or even better, just give that a name and use it:

```
satisfies :: [a -> Bool] -> a -> Bool
satisfies ps x = any ($x) ps

isACOrDigitOrDG = satisfies [(=='a'), isDigit, (`elem` ['d'..'g'])]
```