# Haskell list filtering with two arguments

Tags: list, haskell, filter

I have to write a function, which filters with one argument that results `True`, then filters with another argument which results `False`

I tried this:

```
selectUnless :: (t -> Bool) -> (t -> Bool) -> [t] -> [t]
selectUnless fx gx (x:xs) = filter gx (filter fx (x:xs))
```

But I need that list where "not gx".

For example:

```
selectUnless (>= 2) (==2) [1,2,3,4] == [3,4]
selectUnless even odd [1..50] == [2,4..50]
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Haskell has a [**`not :: Bool -> Bool`**](https://hackage.haskell.org/package/base-4.12.0.0/docs/Prelude.html#v:not) operator that transforms `True` into `False` and vice versa.

The problem is of course that `gx` is *not* a `Bool`, but a function `t -> Bool`. We can however construct a function like:

```
\x -> not (gx x)
```

This will thus apply `not` to the result of `gx x`. Or we can use [**`(.) :: (b -> c) -> (a -> b) -> a -> c`**](https://hackage.haskell.org/package/base-4.12.0.0/docs/Prelude.html#v:.), like:

```
selectUnless :: (t -> Bool) -> (t -> Bool) -> [t] -> [t]
selectUnless fx gx = filter (not . gx) . filter fx
```

We can even make thus completely point-free by using [**`liftA2 :: Applicative f => (a -> b -> c) -> f a -> f b -> f c`**](https://hackage.haskell.org/package/base-4.12.0.0/docs/Control-Applicative.html#v:liftA2):

```
import Control.Applicative(liftA2)

selectUnless :: (t -> Bool) -> (t -> Bool) -> [t] -> [t]
selectUnless = (filter .) . (. (not .)) . liftA2 (&&)
```

or a more elegant solution provided by [@JonPurdy](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/56264267/haskell-list-filtering-with-two-arguments/56264329?noredirect=1#comment99147317_56264329):

```
import Control.Applicative(liftA2)
import Data.Function(on)

pre :: (a -> b) -> (b -> c) -> a -> c
pre = flip (.)

filtered :: (([a] -> [a]) -> ([a] -> [a]) -> c) -> (a -> Bool) -> (a -> Bool) -> c
filtered = (`on` filter)

selectUnless :: (a -> Bool) -> (a -> Bool) -> [a] -> [a]
selectUnless = pre (not .) . filtered (.)
```

Note that your original code could not process an empty list: indeed you only specified the `(x:xs)` pattern in your function for the list, not `[]`. It is not necessary however to use extra patterns here, `filter` already can handle both empty and non-empty lists.

Comment: That point-free version is a little hairy—I’d prefer something like `selectUnless = pre (not .) . filtered (.)` where `pre = flip (.)` and ``filtered = (`on` filter)``, or the partially point-free version `filter (f <&&> not . g)` in the answer by Rein Henrichs

Answer (score 4):

Because `filter f . filter g = filter (\x -> f x && g x)`, we only need some way to invert `g`. This exists as `not`, as Willem mentions. So we have:

```
selectUnless f g = filter (\x -> f x && not (g x))
```

If you want to be a bit more clever, you can lift `&&`:

```
(<&&>) = liftA2 (&&)
infixr 3 <&&>

selectUnless f g = filter (f <&&> not . g)
```

You might even decide that this is concise and intention-revealing enough to not need its own name.

Comment: That operator is even more handy with a `Monad` constraint to make it properly short-circuiting: `a <&&> b = a >>= \case True -> b; False -> pure False` (and analogously for `<||>`)

Comment: @JonPurdy As [was pointed out to me](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/55854726/how-to-nicely-denote-the-alternative-of-three-conditions/55854925#55854925) when I said the same thing... to myself... the `(->) r` Applicative is already short-circuiting. You would only need to do this if you want it to be short-circuiting with arbitrary Monads.

Comment: Right, I should have clarified that this _does_ do short-circuiting evaluation, just not _execution_ of effects for other choices of `m`